# Calculate triangle perimeter and circle's circumference using methods

Tags: java, methods

Users needs to selects one option from the provides the options.If the user selects Triangle, the program prompts the user for coordinates of the vertices and calculate text the perimeter of the triangle. I am not able to solve the errors.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Menu
{
   public static void main (String[] args)  
   {
      int userOption =0;
      userOption = myMenu();
      System.out.println("User selected Option"+userOption);

    if (userOption==1)
     {
       System.out.println("The perimetre of your triangle is" + getPerimeter(trianglePrompt()));
     }      
   //else if (userOption==2)
    //{
      //System.out.println("The circumference of your circle is" + circle(circlePrompt()));
    //}

   }

   public static int myMenu(){
    int userOption;
    Scanner myInput=new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
         System.out.println("Select one of the following options:");  
         System.out.println(" 1. Triangle");  
         System.out.println(" 2. Circle");  
         System.out.println(" 3. Exit");  
         userOption= myInput.nextInt();
  // To read a number of type float, use : myInput.nextFloat();
  // To read a character use : (myInput.next()).charAt(0);
      if (userOption==3){
        System.out.println("Bye");
        System.exit(0);
      }

    } while (userOption !=1 && userOption !=2);
      return userOption;
   }

//METHOD TO SCAN RADIUS FROM USER
   public static double circlePrompt()
  {
      double radius;
      Scanner myRadius= new Scanner(System.in);
      do
      {
         System.out.println("Input a radius of a circle: ");
         radius= myRadius.nextDouble();
         if(radius<0)
            System.out.println("You must input a positive radius");
      }
      while (radius<0);
      return radius;
   }

//METHOD TO CALCULATE THE CIRCUMFERENCE
  public static double circle(double radius)
  {    
      return (2*radius*Math.PI);
  }
// METHOD TO SCAN 6 COORDINATES OF TRIANGLE  
  private Point p1, p2,p3;
  public int trianglePrompt(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3)
  {
  //double x1;
  Scanner scanObject = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Input x1 of a Triangle : ");
  x1= scanObject.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Input x1 of a Triangle : ");
  x2= scanObject.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Input x1 of a Triangle : ");
  x3= scanObject.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Input x1 of a Triangle : ");
  y1= scanObject.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Input x1 of a Triangle : ");
  y2= scanObject.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Input x1 of a Triangle : ");
  y3= scanObject.nextInt();
  //return x1;

 }
    p1 = new Point(x1,y1);
    p2 = new Point(x2,y2);
    p3 = new Point(x3,y3);
   public double getSideA()
   {
      double length = p1.distance(p2);
      return length;
   } 

   public double getSideB()
   {
     double length = p2.distance(p3);
     return length;
   }

   public double getSideC()
      {
      double length = p3.distance(p1);
      return length;
      }

//METHOD TO CALCULATE PERIMETRE OF TRIANGLE BY ADDING ALL THREE SIDES
    public int getPerimeter()
    {
    int as = getSideA(), bs = getSideB(), cs = getSideC();
    return (as + bs + cs); 
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Menu.java:108: error: <identifier> expected
p1 = new Point(x1,y1);
  ^
Menu.java:109: error: <identifier> expected
p2 = new Point(x2,y2);
  ^
Menu.java:110: error: <identifier> expected
p3 = new Point(x3,y3);
  ^
3 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialised `p1`, `p2` and `p3` outside of any method.  It's OK to do that, but only if you initialise them in the same statement as you declare them. 
 So you could write

```
private Point p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
private Point p2 = new Point(x2, y2);
private Point p3 = new Point(x3, y3);
```

instead of

```
private Point p1, p2, p3;
```

and then delete the three lines with the errors.  This will fix your compile error, but it won't make your program work, because it would mean that these lines would run before the values `x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3` have the values that the user enters.

What you really want to do is move the lines

```
p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
p2 = new Point(x2, y2);
p3 = new Point(x3, y3);
```

and so on upwards, before the previous `}` character.  That way, they'll be inside the method where `x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3`  are set, and they'll run after those variables have been given their values.

Answer (score -1):

p1 = new Point(x1,y1);

should be

Point p1 = new Point(x1,y1);

Comment: This will just replace the current compile error with a different one.  Moreover, if you fix that second compile error, the program still won't work.  So this answer is not particularly useful, hence my downvote.